# Detect whether cells of a column are identical to the corresponding rows of other columns

Tags: r, tidyverse

For example, I have a dataframe, I want to know whether the cells in column "x" is identical to the corresponding rows of other columns.

```r
mydf <- data.frame(
  x = paste(letters[1:5]),
  y_1 = c("a","f","g","h","k"),
  y_2 = c("z","x","l","q","n"),
  y_3 = c("q","f","d","c","e")
)
```

I want the result looks like this:

```
 x y_1 y_2 y_3 result
 a   a   z   q    yes
 b   f   x   f     no
 c   g   l   d     no
 d   h   q   c     no
 e   k   n   e    yes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One `dplyr` option may be:

```
mydf %>%
 mutate(result = rowSums(select(., starts_with("y")) == x) > 0)

  x y_1 y_2 y_3 result
1 a   a   z   q   TRUE
2 b   f   x   f  FALSE
3 c   g   l   d  FALSE
4 d   h   q   c  FALSE
5 e   k   n   e   TRUE
```

A small note: I used `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` parameter in the `data.frame()` function, thus not converting strings to factors.

Answer (score 1):

First, convert to character so that we aren't comparing factors with different levels

```
mydf[] <- lapply(mydf, as.character)
```

Then you can lapply over all columns of `mydf` but the first, checking if it is `==` to `mydf$x`. Now you have a logical vector for each column, and you can collapse them into a single vector by applying `|` (or function) successively.

```
mydf$result <- Reduce('|', lapply(mydf[-1], '==', mydf$x))

mydf
#   x y_1 y_2 y_3 result
# 1 a   a   z   q   TRUE
# 2 b   f   x   f  FALSE
# 3 c   g   l   d  FALSE
# 4 d   h   q   c  FALSE
# 5 e   k   n   e   TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another:

```r
 size=ncol(mydf)  
 my_function <- function(mydf) {

  mydf[1] %in% mydf[c(2:size)]
}

mydf$result <- ifelse(apply(mydf, 1,my_function), "Yes", "No")
mydf
#  x y_1 y_2 y_3 result
#1 a   a   z   q    Yes
#2 b   f   x   f     No
#3 c   g   l   d     No
#4 d   h   q   c     No
#5 e   k   n   e    Yes
```